# Pivot a column in excel and only display it in one column

Tags: excel

So I want a column to be displayed in the pivot table but I want to be displayed in one column only, not every data should be displayed in every column.

Here is my data:

[image: Data]

Here is when I pivot the data:

[image: Pivot]

[image: Pivot2]

As you can see **Unit** has a different column in different data.

This is what I want the result should be:

[image: Result]

How to achieve this?

Comment: Try `Rows`<= `Name, Code, Unit`; `Values` <=`Quantity`; `Layout`=> `show in tabular form` and modify some of the other options.  You won't reproduce what you show, but may come close enough.  To reproduce exactly you'll need to write VBA code (or possibly Power Query).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld can you show me a solution?

Comment: Since my suggestion obviously wasn't satisfactory, please **edit your question** to show the VBA or Power Query code you tried. And explain the problem with that attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution so far is what @Ron Rosenfeld suggested. Here's how that looks:

[image]

If it was a simple table (like the one you base you pivot table on), you could simply add a column that merges the quantity and the unit. Like so;

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT([@Quantity];"#");" ";[@Unit])
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

I think this is a matter of separating presentation and calculation. Pivot tables are very useful for dynamically calculating values based on filters. This can't be done with the unit included, and for the most part, the unit is something we want to include with the result. So personally, I would not try to do both at once, I would simply do the calculations and once presenting (like a dashboard, or the export sheet), add the unit to the number. But I am unaware of what you intend to expand and use it for, so I can't say for sure.

I haven't tried this, whether it would suit your needs or not, but [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/pivot-table-with-text-in-values-area/) is a tutorial on how to merge values into a text and add it to your pivot table (similarly like to what I did with the regular one above), there's also a [video version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiFzVInI5sg) of it. Is this more to your liking?